# When will I use camelCase in F# when exporting to other .NET languages?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, f#, naming-conventions

Based on [The F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/#31-naming-conventions), F# should use `PascalCase` to conform .NET Framework naming conventions.

Suppose I'm using C# or VB.NET and want to import a F# library, when should I expect a `camelCase` convention to appear in this library?

Comment: not sure why you are asking, if everything uses PascalCase, then never?

Comment: This will depend on whoever (how) wrote that particular library, however you should expect functions and other values (defined with `let`) appear with camelCase. These are usually public.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [FsCheck library](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/index.html), and specifically its [Gen module](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/0a0507acafe58da8da0c0c8a17aa1ee9ff1ecfd0/src/FsCheck/Gen.fs#L109). (There are other examples in the FsCheck source code, but this one's easy to read). FsCheck is designed to be used from both F# and C#, and the design of the Gen module reflects that:

```
module Gen =
    // ...

    [<CompiledName("Map"); EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>]
    let map f (gen:Gen<_>) = gen.Map f

    [<CompiledName("Sized"); EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>]
    let sized fgen = Gen (fun n r -> let (Gen m) = fgen n in m n r)

    [<CompiledName("Sized"); CompilerMessage("This method is not intended for use from F#.", 10001, IsHidden=true, IsError=false)>]
    let sizedFunc (sizedGen : Func<int,Gen<_>>) =
        sized sizedGen.Invoke
```

Ignore the implementation of these functions for a moment and look at their names, and the `CompiledName` attribute that each has been given. When you invoke the `map` function from F#, you'll invoke it as `Gen.map`, but when you use it from C#, the `CompiledName` attribute will cause you to see it with the name `Gen.Map`. Likewise with the `sized` function, which will be called `Gen.sized` when invoked from F# code, which will be seen with the name `Gen.Sized` when invoked from C#. Note also how there's a second function with the same `CompiledName` (when seen from C#), but the F# code has a distinction between `Gen.sized` and `Gen.sizedFunc` (and the F# compiler will also warn you if you try to use `Gen.sizedFunc` that "This method is not intended for use from F#"), because that overload expects the function type used by C# code, and is purely for the convenience of C# coders using the library. (F# functions use the `FSharpFunc` type, which behaves differently from the C# `Func` type in some situations).

However, your question wasn't so much "How should I write my F# library so that it can be used by C# coders?". Rather, your question was, "As a C# coder, what should I expect from F# libraries in terms of naming conventions?" And the answer to *that* question is: **It depends on the library you're using.**

As you've pointed out, the F# Component Design Guidelines recommend PascalCase names for functions designed to be used from calling code. And FsCheck is a good example of a library that did it right. But not all libraries were written with the intent that they be easily used from C#. Some libraries were written thinking only about other F# code using them, and those libraries will **not** necessarily conform to the design guidelines, because the F# convention is to use camelCase for function names.

So although this isn't a totally satisfactory answer, it's the best one I can give you, because I don't know which libraries you'll be using.